# Architecture questions should go

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Saw the [list of StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-sites), but it's not clear where to discuss and ask general architecture questions, network issues, and indeed the thorny issue of scalability!

These kind of questions aren't directly programming, and so therefore don't fit on Stack Overflow. (Even though potentially related to programming of course.)

Where does one go to ask, ponder and query these onions?

Answer (score 5):

It's called [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). The 2nd part of the trilogy. It is foccused on network architecture and scalability. However if you are referring to development scalabality I can't why it won't be allowed on SO.

If you problem is related to your personal computer you can also look at [Super User](http://superuser.com). The 3rd part of the trilogy focusses on computer hardware and software problems.